# code is resulting only first value of for loop eg. 1

Tags: c++

[when we gives input 3 the expected answer is 6 but actual answer I getting is 1

[image: ][1]]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: move the `return` outside of the `for` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `return` statement is reached without control, so in the first loop step the function will return `1`.

The first step of the loop `i=1`, so `ans +=i`  is `1`.

You need to let the `for` loop complete and then return the `ans`.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int sum(int n)
{
    int ans=0;
    for(int i=1; i<n; i++){
        ans += i;
    }
    return ans;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^
}

int32_t main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n; 
    cout << sum(n) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write "return" outside of cycle.

Comment: This answer is fitting only as a comment. If you choose to answer the question, supply code examples and explanations